# Difference between array/vector types in Common Lisp?

Tags: arrays, vector, types, common-lisp

What is the difference between the types `vector`, `simple-vector`, `array` and `simple-array`?
I know that vectors are a subtype of arrays and cannot be multidimensional.
The "simple-" versions seem to be types, and the rest classes. So the types might be more complex, to specify the type.

Which type-specifiers should I use? What is the best way to specify a vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A vector is an one-dimensional array.

They are [simple](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#simple) if they are not *displaced*, have no *fill pointer*, **and** are not *expressly adjustable*. A simple-vector also needs to be able to hold elements of any type.

> Which type-specifiers should I use?

I guess that depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Why exactly `simple-vector` needs to be able to hold elements of any type? Suppose I want to have a one-dimensional, constant size container of elements of same predetermined type, should I stick to `simple-array` then?

Answer (score 5):

Rainer [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28908613/850781) the [positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_statement) part of your question.

Here is the answer to the [normative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_statement) part:

> Which type-specifiers should I use?

You should *not* use any, unless you know very well what you are doing.

Type annotations in Common Lisp are optional; they are intended for the *experts* for the performance tuning. It is highly unlikely that you will ever gain any meaningful benefit from type declarations and you are highly likely to be hurt by them. E.g., if your type annotation is wrong you might get a segfault instead of an error message (when combined with unsafe code).

Additionally, the effect may be *the opposite* of what one might expect. E.g., using specialized arrays (e.g., `(array double-float)`) to reduce memory footprint may result in an *increased* garbage collection because every array access may have to box a new `double-float`.

Essentially, type annotations are *usually* micro optimizations which should be accompanied by careful profiling.

Comment: What is an expert, why are type annotations meant for them, and how does one become an expert so you can use them?  An array of single- or double-floats ends up being a not-really-expert and common use of typed arrays, when supported by the implementation, that really makes a difference.  Most implementations actually make a flat array instead of one with boxed values.  If type declarations can hurt, at least explain why (e.g. what happens when we also `(declare (optimize (safety 0)))`), don't just state so.